# Вывод строки перед и после

Tags: c#

В `.txt` записана такие строки, к примеру

```
stroka1
stroka-
stroka2
```

Вопрос такой: как через код, вывести:
только те строки, которые находятся "над" и "после" строки, которая кончается с `-` 
Вывод должен быть таким:

```
stroka1
stroka2
```

Возможно что-то будет типа ..`.EndsWith("-")-1);`

Comment: Добавьте пример данных и вывода, где кроме сигнальной строки и строк рядом с ней есть и другие.

Comment: ... или например две сигнальных строки подряд

Comment: @VladD, или через одну)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала можно попробовать так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string prev = "", current = "", next = "";
    foreach (var s in File.ReadLines("TextFile.txt").Concat(new[] { "" }))
    {
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = s;
        if (IsSignal(current))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prev);
            Console.WriteLine(next);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool IsSignal(string s)
{
    return s.EndsWith("-");
}
```

PS: Если вы используете .NET 4.7.1 или выше, вместо `.Concat(new[] { "" })` можно использовать `.Append("")`

---

То же самое с использованием [`morelinq`](https://morelinq.github.io):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var list
        in File.ReadLines("TextFile.txt")
               .Prepend("")
               .Concat("")
               .Windowed(3)
               .Select(w => w.ToList()))
    {
        if (IsSignal(list[1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(list[2]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool IsSignal(string s)
{
    return s.EndsWith("-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       var s = File.ReadLines("input.txt").ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
        {
            if (s[i].EndsWith("-"))
            {
                if (i >= 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s[i - 1]);
                }
                if(i + 1 < s.Count)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(s[i + 1]);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

думаю, тут будет проще и понятнее.

Comment: Нужно упомянуть, что здесь в память загружается файл целиком. Можно написать, кстати, `File.ReadAllLines(...)` вместо `File.ReadLines(...).ToList()`

Comment: И еще, у вас есть проверка, что мы не выйдем за пределы в `s[i - 1]`, но нет проверки у `s[i + 1]`. Что, если последняя строка окажется "сигнальной"?

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас исправлю. File.ReadAllLines(...) нельзя будет обращаться по индексу.

Comment: В массиве нельзя обращаться по индексу? [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path); Если бы он возвращал массив((

Comment: `public static string[] ReadAllLines(string path)` ну дал же ведь нормальную ссылку: readALLlines

Comment: Извиняюсь не заметил.