# найти следуйщее значения после введённого

Tags: c#

От руки ввел какое то число, к примеру, `4`, оно также где-то находится в `.txt` файле, но вопрос в том что, как получить следуйщее значение после того, которое я ввел от руки?

Содержимое `.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

то на выходе должно быть значение `5`

Через цикл - не вариант..то есть по сути, прочитать значение дальше на **одно** от того что ввел

```
var next = GetNextFromFile(filename, current);
            Console.WriteLine(next);
        }
    }
    public string GetNextFromFile(string filename, string str)
    {
        return File.ReadLines(filename).SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals(str)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

до сих пор подчеркивает `GetNextFromFile`

Comment: "Через цикл - не вариант." ??

Comment: @Igor "не вариант" потому-что, если все числа изменить на любые слова, какие - без разницы, цикл не поможет, а код должен работать и так и так

Comment: А в файле только цифры или может быть что-то ещё?

Comment: Не, цикл будет работать и со словами... просто надо понимать как его писать, просто перебор строчек подряд... и нет разницы цифры или слова введены.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин причем тут перебор? Цикл это перебор, хотя в каком та плане, да.." может быть что-то ещё" - все что угодно можно туда засунуть, просто хочется код уникальный чтобы работал в любых условиях :)

Comment: А почему вы решили что цикл будет не в любых условиях работать? Как напишите так и будет работать...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не нравится через цикл - будем клепать на linq ;)

Итак, у нас есть файл filename и current - значение введённое с клавиатуры.

Поехали:

```
void Main()
{
    var filename = @"C:\downloads\123.txt";
    string current = "4";
    var next = GetNextFromFile(filename, current);
    next.Dump(); // 5
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static string GetNextFromFile(string filename, string str)
{
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    if(!data.Any(x => string.Equals(x, str)))
        throw new Exception("No such string");

    return data.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals(str)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Обратите внимание: если введённое значение будет в последней строке - то следующей строки нет, мы вылетим с ошибкой. По-хорошему нужно и эту ситуацию обработать, а не только отсутствие строки в файле.

Ну а так на шару достаточно и однострочником обойтись:

```
public static string GetNextFromFile(string filename, string str)
{
    return File.ReadLines(filename).SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals(str)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Но вообще, в этой задаче я бы лично не стал бы использовать linq, а написал бы простой цикл. А вариант @Bullson ещё проще - там даже цикла нет.

Comment: щя протестью)..

Comment: Красота, теперь цикла нет )))

Comment: Лучше `FirstorDefault` иначе упадешь если не будет нужной строки

Comment: подчеркивает `Dump`

Comment: @Rolly Напишите вместо этого `Console.WriteLine(next);` - а `.Dump()` - это самая замечательная вещь, за которую я обожаю linqpad

Comment: А что логичнее когда не найдёт выдать исключение или null?

Comment: теперь подчеркиает `GetNextFromFile` ;)

Comment: @Rolly А, у вас наверняка на non static ругается - уберите this (поправил у себя) и сделайте метод статическим.

Comment: @AK, _File.ReadLines_ - не читает весь файл в память

Comment: @Grundy Да, сначала был комментарий к ReadAllLines, а потом я уже вписал версию с ReadLines

Comment: вот это высвечивает "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.GetNextFromFile(string, string)'
"

Comment: Тогда стоит перенести комментарий к нужному блоку, сейчас кажется он именно к последнему относится

Comment: Отлично 8-)))))

Comment: Rolly Вы реально уверены, что вам linq-версия подходит больше, чем код @Bullson ?

Comment: @AK дап, главное чтобы работало, Bullson написал с простыми числами, а я в вопросе писал, что там может быть все что угодно, хоть числа хоть слова, только почему получил минус...могу только гадать.

Comment: В одном случае выбрасывается исключение а в другом возвращается null...

Answer (score 2):

Можно по-простому, по рабоче-крестьянски без LINQ

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int index = list.IndexOf(4);

int next = 0;
if (index + 1 < list.Count)
{
    next = list[index + 1];
}
```

Comment: Вот этот вариант я бы принял галкой. Только у него там строки: и строки файла и строки введённые с клавиатуры. я лично оставил string...

Comment: @AK это я так на скорую руку написал.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью [`morelinq`](https://morelinq.github.io/) решение могло бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
string[] seq = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
string target = "4";
string result = seq.Pairwise((a, b) => (a, b))
                   .Where(t => t.a == target)
                   .Select(t => t.b)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Если число, которое необходимо найти и которое необходимо вывести находятся не рядом, а отстоят друг от друга на некоторое смещение, то можно воспользоваться методом `Lag`:

```
string result = seq.Lag(1, (a, b) => (a, b))
                   .Where(t => t.b == target)
                   .Select(t => t.a)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Обратите внимание, a и b здесь поменялись местами. Первый параметр метода `Lag` - смещение между нашими элементами.

Comment: Спасибо, за наводку на интересную библиотеку.

Comment: Да ладно, вы не знали про morelinq?

Comment: Нет, впервые увидел :) Есть отрицательные стороны у работы в одиночку, меньше случайных источников полезной информации.

Comment: Вот вам тогда еще пачка примеров: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790228/218063), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/778733/218063), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/766316/218063), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787175/218063), [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767636/218063)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.